# Yii2 - dropDownList to populate textInput

Tags: jquery, yii2, active-form

I have this View:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
   <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->dropDownList(['E' => 'Data Entry', 'S' => 'Mark Entry'], ['prompt' => 'Select Option']) ?>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
   <?= $form->field($model, 'detail')->textInput(['maxlength' => 20, 'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('detail')]) ?>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is that when I click on the `dropDownList`, If the value is **Data Entry** then the textInput will be **Data Entry**. Then if the value is **Mark Entry**, then the textInput will be **Mark Entry**.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `id` attribute for each input to get their values by **jQuery**:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->dropDownList(['E' => 'Data Entry', 'S' => 'Mark Entry'], ['id' => 'firstInput', prompt'=>'Select Option']) ?>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'detail')->textInput(['id' => 'secondInput', maxlength' => 20, 'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('detail')]) ?>
</div>
```

And your **jQuery** code:

```
$('#firstInput').change(function() {
   var firstInputValue = $(this).val();
   $('#secondInput').val(firstInputValue);
});
```

Comment: you must always use even delegation to avoid problems.